# MVC4 application, How to make every element (dynamically created table or div) to send ajax request to controller with its ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamically-generated

i have a problem and i hope you have the solution. It's a Model-View-Controller-4 .net application.

I dynamically create elements (table and div) and i need them to refresh somehow, but each element to send its own ajax request with it's id or something like that, so when the updated information come back from the controller, the old is replaced.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of what you want?

Comment: I have a list of computers and for each i'm monitoring its services, their status, memory they are using (the process using that service) and so. When that list goes to view, i'm creating a table for each computer and i need it to refresh all the time but and the idea is to use ajax request for each table so it is much faster than waiting all computers to refresh then update the information. after the ajax request i send partial view to replace the old table. when the information comes back i don't know where to put it (in which table)

Comment: Hide the id of the computer in your table.
You can hide it like this: <table data-id="1"></table>
I think data-something is a normalized way of adding custom attribute.
Then you pass this id to your ajax request.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp